# iOS PWA: How to (re-)enable pull to refresh?

Tags: ios, progressive-web-apps, mobile-safari

There are several questions on Stack Overflow asking how to disable pull-to-refresh, whether when their web-apps are visited in the native iOS Safari browser, or as a standalone (Homescreen) application.

My question is how to *enable* it. Somehow with my app, the pull-to-refresh functionality works well with Safari, but not when the app is open as a standalone Homescreen application.

I'd like to add any relevant information needed, except that I don't know what to specify. Here's the abbreviated `manifest.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "x",
  "short_name": "x",
  "description": "x",
  "dir": "auto",
  "id": "https://www.myapp.io/",
  "lang": "en-US",
  "display": "standalone"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like pull to refresh is explicitly disabled for standalone and fullscreen PWA apps on iOS.

I ended up reimplementing it with a standalone check, [pulltorefresh.js](https://github.com/BoxFactura/pulltorefresh.js), and some javascript glue.

```js
const standalone =
  navigator.standalone ||
  window.matchMedia("(display-mode: standalone)").matches;
if (!standalone) {
  return; // not standalone; no pull to refresh needed
}

PullToRefresh.init({
  onRefresh() {
    location.reload();
  },
});
```

Comment: will this play nicely on android? because the issue iOS only. Also please check my answer I posted to make it more friendly to react.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Joonas, for react.

```
npm install pulltorefreshjs
npm install @types/pulltorefreshjs
```

I added this to my root file (main.tsx)

```
import PullToRefresh from "pulltorefreshjs"

...

const standalone = window.matchMedia("(display-mode: standalone)").matches

if (standalone) {
    PullToRefresh.init({
        onRefresh() {
            window.location.reload()
        },
    })
}
```

not sure how it will affect Android devices though.

Comment: You could check the user agent to make sure you only execute it on iPhone and not Android: /iPhone|iPad|iPod/i.test(navigator.userAgent)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to build a workaround for this that works on progressive web apps on iOS using jQuery. The key appears to be 'overscroll-behavior: none;' on the html element. Comment that out, and this doesn't work.

This code prompts the user to "Pull to refresh..." if the user pulls down at all and shows a different message once the page begins reloading. These can easily be swapped with more traditional loading icons.

Hoping this helps.

```js
//Pull down to refresh
$(document).ready(function() {
  let startY = 0;
  let dist = 0;
  const threshold = 50;
  const $refreshIndicator = $('#refreshIndicator');

  $(window).on('touchstart', function(e) {
    startY = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
  });

  $(window).on('touchmove', function(e) {
    if (window.scrollY === 0) {
      const touchY = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
      dist = touchY - startY;

      if (dist > threshold / 2) {
        $refreshIndicator.show();
        $refreshIndicator.text('> Pull to refresh');
      }

      if (dist > threshold) {
        $refreshIndicator.text('> Refreshing...');
        location.reload();
      }
    }
  });

  $(window).on('touchend', function() {
    startY = 0;
    dist = 0;
    $refreshIndicator.hide();
  });
});


var mouseY = 0;
var startMouseY = 0;

$('body').on('touchstart', function(ev) {
  mouseY = ev.pageY;
  startMouseY = mouseY;
  $(document).on('touchmove', function(e) {
    if (e.pageY > mouseY) {
      var d = e.pageY - startMouseY;
      console.log(d);
      if (d >= 200) {
        $(document).unbind("touchstart");
        //get url of current page
        window.location.href = window.location.href;
      }

      $('body').css('margin-top', d / 4 + 'px');
    } else
      $(document).unbind("touchstart");


  });
});

$('body').on('mousedown', function(ev) {
  mouseY = ev.pageY;
  startMouseY = mouseY;
  $(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    if (e.pageY > mouseY) {
      var d = e.pageY - startMouseY;
      console.log(d);
      if (d >= 400) {
        $(document).unbind("mousemove");
        //send user to current location
        window.location.href = window.location.href;
      }

      $('body').css('margin-top', d / 4 + 'px');
    } else
      $(document).unbind("mousemove");


  });
});
$('body').on('mouseup', function() {
  $('body').css('margin-top', '0px');
  $(document).unbind("mousemove");
});
$('body').on('mouseleave', function() {
  $('body').css('margin-top', '0px');
  $(document).unbind("mousemove");
});
```

```css
html {
  background-size: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overscroll-behavior: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="refreshIndicator" style="display:none; text-align: center;">Pull to refresh...</div>

  <div> Your content here </div>
</body>

</html>
```